# Try to loop condition why i getting undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I have some questions about my code.
My code look like this

```js
var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"};

var combine = [ {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},
        {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];

for(key in combine[0]){

   if(key.length > 1){
    var num = key.length;
    console.log(key, data.key);  
    }
}
```

My purpose is try to return data.Q1 and data.Q2 with use data.key but when i `console.log(key, data.key);`

Keys are Q1, Q5 but data.key is undefined i think its must be "Male" and "USA"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVFy1.png)

Comment: Because you are looking for "key" not the variable....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `key` is dynamic, use `[]` bracket notation to access the property. This will allow you to evaluate `key` dynamically:

```js
 var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"};

var combine = [ {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},
                {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];

for(key in combine[0]){
    if(key.length > 1){
    var num = key.length;
    console.log(key, data[key]);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `console.log(key, data.key);` to `console.log(key, data[key]);`

```js
var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"};

var combine = [ {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},
                {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];

for(key in combine[0]){
        if(key.length > 1){
        var num = key.length;
        console.log(key, data[key]);     
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

key in combine[0] imply the key name of the object.

So key.length gives you the length of key i.e **Q1 's length**

use data[key] to get the whole object

```js
var data = {
  "Q1": "Male",
  "Q5": "USA"
};

var combine = [{
    "Q1": "Male",
    "Q5": "USA"
  },
  {
    "Q1": "Male",
    "Q5": "Japan"
  }
];

for (key in combine[0]) {
  if (key.length > 1) {
    var num = key.length;
    console.log(key);
    console.log("key's length--", key.length);
    console.log("key's data--", data[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` object is map. Try using `data[key]`

```js
var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"};
var combine = [ {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},
                {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];
for(key in combine[0]){
   if(key.length > 1){
        var num = key.length;
        console.log(key, data[key]);     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.key` tries to access property `key` in your data object which is undefined.

Try using `[]` brackets.

Example:

```
 var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"};

var combine = [ {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},
                {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];

for(key in combine[0]){
        if(key.length > 1){
        var num = key.length;
        console.log(key, data[key]);     
        }
    }
```